# PhotoEditorSDK : export to server without auto download?

Tags: javascript, html, photoeditorsdk

I am using [photoeditorsdk](https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com) in my Angular app. There is an export to server function in the docs:

```
editor.export(
  PhotoEditorSDK.RenderType.DATAURL, 
  PhotoEditorSDK.ImageFormat.JPEG,
  0.8 // JPEG quality: 80%
).then((dataUrl) => {
  // Upload to server
})
```

I get the image `dataUrl`, but the image is also downloaded at the browser.  I want to prevent the download.

Answer (score 3):

I got help from their support, in the configuration guide : https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/html5/v4-DesktopUI/introduction/configuration at the bottom is the export object, just need to pass `download: false`.