# PhotoEditorSDK prevent download when exporting manually

Tags: angular, photoeditorsdk

I tried [PhotoEditorSDK : export to server without auto download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286778/photoeditorsdk-export-to-server-without-auto-download), but that did not help me. The following code still downloads the file to the client.

By the time I get to the `then` part of the export promise, the act of exporting has already downloaded the file to the client even though I've explicitly stated that `editor.export.download = false`.

Have I misunderstood something in the export part?

If I set `editor.enableExport: true`, I must listen to the `editor.on('export')` event. This works fine, except that the data delivered to this event is the original image data, and not the manipulated data present inside the editor. By exporting manually, I get the rendered content, but it ignores the download flag. :-(

P.S. Console states that I'm using v4.1.0 of PhotoEditorSDK.

### Creating the editor

```ts
this.editor = new PhotoEditorDesktopUI({
  container: this.el.nativeElement,
  license: license,
  assets: {
    baseUrl: '/assets/photoeditorsdk' // see angular-cli.json for configuraton
  },
  responsive: true,
  style: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  },
  editor: {
    image: this.image,
    enableExport: false,
    export: {
      download: false
    }
  },
});
```

### Exporting from the editor

```ts
this.editor.export(
  PhotoEditorSDK.RenderType.DATAURL, // Export as `Image` object
  PhotoEditorSDK.ImageFormat.JPEG,   // Export as JPEG
  0.8                                // JPEG quality: 80%
).then((data) => {
  // Do something with the imagedata
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of the documentation is wrong. The `export` function now takes a single argument `download` of type `Boolean`. So in order to export the image, you'll need to do the following:

```
this.editor.export(false)
  .then((data) => {
    // Do something with the imagedata
  });
```

The export format, file type and quality are now controlled via the editor options.